# Automated query testing against a knowledge base in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I have a db with some facts and a file with some predicates that I defined.

```
 /* facts.pl */
 person(dan).
 dog_person(dan).
 dog(spot).


 /* predicates.pl with facts imported */
 :- [facts].

 has_dog(X,Y) :- (person(X),dog_person(X),dog(Y)).
 whatever(X,Y) :- (something(X),something_else(Y)).
 ... many more
```

In order to test the predicates I defined I need to run a list of queries against my db. I'm wondering if there is another way to do this where I don't have to input each query one by one.

```
 /* Query */
 ?- hasdog(X,dan).         %(click)

 /* Out would be something like */
 X = dog.                  %(click)
 ... many more
```

For example, is there a way to abstract the queries into their own file/function so that I can loop through them without stopping?

```
 > swipl predicates.pl queries.pl

 /* Query */
 ?- hasdog(X,dan).
 X = dog.

 /* Query */
 ?- hasdog(X,dan).
 X = dog.
 ...

 Done.
```

Comment: I think your database have problems because you are trying to define atoms with capital letter then they are no more atom but variables. For example `Dan vs dan`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'll edit my post to reflect that. However, this db is a substitute for the real one and my actual db isn't having trouble. What I'm looking for is a way to apply all of my queries to the database, instead of performing each one at a time.

Comment: TO do that you have to write tests, where you put all your queries in a file in some predicates then call that predicate and compare the expected result with actual result. Kind of JUnit test.

Comment: see [Prolog Unit Test](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27))

Comment: Better replace `:- [facts].` by `:- ensure_loaded(facts).`

Comment: Put the testing code in a file, and add a top-level predicate test/0 that makes the queries.